# MongoDB Aggregation Unique Pair os values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[Mongo Playgroud](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9DbSSGnBR56)

Lets say I have this data:

```
[
  { "PartnerId": 1, PartnerName: "AA" },
  { "PartnerId": 2, PartnerName: "BB" },
  { "PartnerId": 1, PartnerName: "AA" },
  { "PartnerId": 3, PartnerName: "CC" },
  { "PartnerId": 3, PartnerName: "CC" },
  { "PartnerId": 2, PartnerName: "BB" }
]
```

And I would like to extract only Unique of pairs, so the result would be:

```
[
  { "PartnerId": 1, PartnerName: "AA" },
  { "PartnerId": 2, PartnerName: "BB" },
  { "PartnerId": 3, PartnerName: "CC" }
]
```

Should I do a Map & Filter or just a Group & Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by both the fields
- `$project` to show real fields name

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        PartnerId: "$PartnerId",
        PartnerName: "$PartnerName"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      PartnerId: "$_id.PartnerId",
      PartnerName: "$_id.PartnerName"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ay_dbRQA-iL)